# How to code to zoom in or zoom out in coreplot / ios 8?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-plot

I had draw a line graph which contain two y axis and x axis.

Now i want give limitation /restriction for zoom- in and zoom -out.
I used following code to give limitation to

```
-(CPTPlotRange*)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    if([newRange locationDouble] < 0)
    {
        if(coordinate == CPTCoordinateX)
            return  [(CPTXYPlotSpace*)space xRange];
        else if(coordinate == CPTCoordinateY)
            return [(CPTXYPlotSpace*)space yRange];
    }
    if([newRange locationDouble] < 1000)
    {
        if(coordinate == CPTCoordinateX)
            return  [(CPTXYPlotSpace*)space xRange];
        else if(coordinate == CPTCoordinateY)
            return [(CPTXYPlotSpace*)space yRange];
    }

    return newRange;
}

and for zooming i used following code

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint

{
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

   // plotSpace.delegate = self;


    NSInteger xAxisMin = 0;
    NSInteger xAxisMax = 15;

    NSInteger yAxisMin = 0;
    NSInteger yAxisMax = 100;



    if ((plotSpace.xRange>= [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(2*(xAxisMax-xAxisMin))])||



        ((plotSpace.yRange>= [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(2*(yAxisMax-yAxisMin))])))



    {



        //return NO;

        plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

        CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;


        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

        plotSpace.delegate = self;

        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMax - xAxisMin)];

        plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMax - yAxisMin)];

        plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

        return YES;

    }

    else if ((plotSpace.xRange<= [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble((xAxisMax-xAxisMin)/2)])||



             ((plotSpace.yRange<= [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble((yAxisMax-yAxisMin)/2)])))

    {

        //[_hostingView setAllowPinchScaling:NO];

         plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

        //return NO;


        CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

        plotSpace.delegate = self;

        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xAxisMax - xAxisMin)];

        plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMax - yAxisMin)];

        plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

       // [hostingView setAllowPinchScaling:YES];



        return YES;

    }

    return YES;      



}
```

but problem is this above shouldScaleBy: delegate does not call.
I can't understand why this is not called.

please give code to to zoom and zoom out to some extend.

Comment: This Link might help you out where you can find your queries related core plot

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-plot?sort=active

Comment: i already looked that question please give some example

Comment: You should use the plot space parameter passed to your delegate. This lets you use the same delegate for more than one plot space and makes the code easier to reuse in another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-plotSpace:shouldScaleBy:aboutPoint:` method is only called in response to a pinch gesture on the hosting view. The `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` method is called for every change so you can do all of your limit checks there.